# How to use Break Statement in BAL of IBM ODM

Tags: ibm-odm

for example i want an functionality which performs same functionality as Break statement. I can write the break statement in IRL Language but how can we write it in BAL Language?

Answer (score 0):

IRL is a low-level language that includes for loop statements.  The break is present in IRL to immediately exit a loop.

BAL is a high-level language that is implemented on top of a rule engine.  The primary function of a rule engine is to abstract the execution logic such that it can be declared without considering sequence of the rule statements.  BAL is designed for [declarative programmning](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming#) with natural languages like English.  So it is missing the point of the technology to code procedural constructs with BAL.

Having said that, there are ways to introduce some sequence into groups of rules using rule flows within ODM.  So you could set a variable in a rule flow task and then check for that setting and skip a later rule task in the flow as one way to short circuit the execution of later rules.  This is somewhat akin to a "break".